# PM2 : NodeJS based process manager won't reboot on file change

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am following pm'2 [doc](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/) to set it up for a restart on every time a file changes in my app directory. However, it doesen't seem to restart the app when I change the file. The "watching" flag is enabled as well:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. For anyone else having this same issue.

For some reason, pm2 needs an app name flag to be passed at the time of it's launch to be able to monitor and restart the service on directory changes.

```
pm2 start index.js --watch --name=myapp
```